# How to set Rank function in hypersql database(HSQLDB)

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb, hypersql

I am switching Database MYSQL to HyperSQL, but i am facing an issue regarding rank functionality.
here i'm showing a simple MYSQL query,

```
SELECT    first_name,
          age,
          gender,
          @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS rank
FROM      person p, (SELECT @Rank := 0) r
ORDER BY  age;
```

How to convert it in HyperSQL Query or is there any alternate way to set variable in HyperSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB supports an SQL Standard function that provides the same functionality

```
SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() over ()
FROM (SELECT first_name,
          age,
          gender
      FROM  person
      ORDER BY  age) p
```